# SyntaxError in Look#input

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have problem:

```
/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:9: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tASSOC
...tag  :action => 'at', :method = > post);@output_buffer.safe_...
...                               ^

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:12: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'..._field_tag "text2", nil, :size" => 30);@output_buffer.safe_c...
...                               ^

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:15: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' <input type="submit"/>
                         ^

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:15: unterminated string meets end of file

/home/rene/ruby_dev/ch05/txt2fields/app/views/look/input.html:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

Extracted source (around line #9):

```
6:     <h1>Les champs de saisie (champs de texte) version 2</h1>
7:     Cette application Ruby on Rails lit du texte saisi.
8:     <br>
9:     <%= form_tag  :action => 'at', :method = > post%>
10:       Veuillez saisir votre nom.
11:       <br>
12:       <%= text_field_tag "text2", nil, :size" => 30%>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, line 9

`:method = > post%>`

should be

`:method => post%>`

There is one unnecessary space.

---

And line 12

`:size" => 30`

should be

`:size => 30`

Symbols don't end with quotations.